# AngularJS call a function in another controller from a link

Tags: function, angularjs, call

I need to call a function in another controller from a link.

Now I'm in controller DashboardCtrl and I need to call function aggiornaListamedici() that is in controller AggiornaCtrl, how can I do that starting from a link??

This is my code now:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <a href="#/aggiorna" ng-click="aggiornaListamedici()">
        <span ng-class="{button_download:true}"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**ROUTING**

```
medicoFvgAppModule.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/aggiorna', {templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html', controller: 'AggiornaCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/dashboard'});
}])
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
medicoFvgAppControllers.controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope','$location','$rootScope',
    function($scope,$location,$rootScope) {
        // my controller dashboard
    }]);

medicoFvgAppControllers.controller('AggiornaCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope','$http', '$timeout', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $timeout) {

    $scope.aggiornaListamedici = function(){
        // my function
    }
}]);
```

Comment: You shall use service for that

Comment: Can you explain me how to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here.

The most "right way" is to use a service that will do the job, and inject this service in both AggiornaCtrl and DashboardCtrl. If you're new to AngularJS you might want to read [the official docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.injecting_controllers) to know how to do it.

The other option is to make a common Controller that will be the parent of your two Controller, using controller inheritance, as described in [this blog post](http://blog.omkarpatil.com/2013/02/controller-inheritance-in-angularjs.html). It is more a trick than an "official way of doing thing", but this hack has been proven very useful to me so far.